# SQL Server 2008 installed, though running version is still 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

A while back I installed SQL Server 2008 on a development machine which already had Sql Server 2005 express from Visual Studio. When I look in my programs, I see 'Microsoft Sql Server 2008', which contains the management studio, etc. As well I can see 'MS Sql Server 2005'.

When I run a query in Management Studio 2008 to select the version running on my machine, it comes up as 2005, and leaves me scratching my head. When I look in the configuration manager, all I see is the SQLEXPRESS instance running ...

Are there any "quick" solutions to get 2008 running instead of 2005, considering 2008 is installed?

Comment: Check in `Administrative Tools -> Services` to see which versions you actually have running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using the SQL Server 2005 Configuration Manager you will only see 2005 instances and lower.

To view instances of SQL Server 2008 you will want to make sure you are using SQL Sever 2008 Configuration Manager.

The final option would be to View All services using the Service Control Manager.  Here you will need to look at what instances of SQL Server you have running on the machine.

Comment: After looking at both the 2005 and 2008 configuration managers, they both use SQLEXPRESS as their instance names. Should I look into changing the 2008 instance name?

Comment: yes [this text is only to reach the min length to add a comment]

Comment: Yes its definitely not a good idea to have two SQL Server instances on the same physical box with the same instance name.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find all the  instance names, one way is to run powershell and execute the following

`PS C:\> gwmi win32_service -filter "name like 'MSSQL%'" | fl DisplayName, pathname`

For me the result is

```
DisplayName : SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)
pathname    : "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\B
              inn\sqlservr.exe" -sSQLEXPRESS

DisplayName : SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS2005)
pathname    : "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\Binn\sqlserv
              r.exe" -sSQLEXPRESS2005

DisplayName : SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (MSSQLSERVER)
pathname    : "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\
              Binn\fdlauncher.exe" -s MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER

DisplayName : SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)
pathname    : "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\
              Binn\sqlservr.exe" -sMSSQLSERVER

DisplayName : SQL Server Active Directory Helper
pathname    : "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared\sqladhlp90.exe"

DisplayName : SQL Active Directory Helper Service
pathname    : "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Shared\SQLADHLP.EXE"

DisplayName : SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER)
pathname    : "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS10.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\bi
              n\msmdsrv.exe" -s "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS10.M
              SSQLSERVER\OLAP\Config"
```

Look for the one that has MSSQL10 and make sure that the service is started. Then use that instance name when connecting via SSMS.

If for some reason you didn't install into the default structure you can always visit the Exe directly and check its version for something like 2007.100.xxx

I happen to have 2005 and 2008 express as well as 2008 standard

If I was better at PowerShell I would have piped the PathName to get the version info