# How to run default SQL Server from 2008 to 2010

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have Sql Server 2005 and 2008 installed on my PC. By default 2008 is running and it is connected in visual studio 2010.

How could I make Sql server 2005 as default sql server and make connection with VS 2010.

Thank You

(Please tell me solutions without Uninstalling any of the Sql servers.)

Comment: Each should have unique instance name so it should be only about specifying correct connection string. Or I don't understand your question.

Comment: @ladislav: now is SQL server 2008 is running in Windows Services. How could i stop 2008 and make 2005 running ? Thank You

Comment: SQL Server 2010 does not exist.

Comment: What do you mean by 'make Sql server 2005 as default'? Either way, VS will be able to connect; it's a matter of a connection string.

Comment: @p.campbell : VS is not detecting SQL 2005 now. It is able to connect with SQL 2008 only.

Comment: If you install SQL server 2008 over SQL server 2005, you attached database might have been upgraded to SQL server 2008 automatically.

Comment: If you're talking about changing the *instance names* so that your 2005 server would become the one to respond to `server=(local).....` instead of the 2008 instance : that can only be achieved by un- and re-installing. You cannot change the instance name from default to something else (or vice-versa) without re-installing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not really clear what's being asked here, but it could be

1) *How do I find out if SQL 2005 is installed and what is its instance name.*

John Hartsocks [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916115/sql-server-2008-installed-though-running-version-is-still-2005/5916159#5916159) to [SQL Server 2008 installed, though running version is still 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916115/sql-server-2008-installed-though-running-version-is-still-2005/5916479#5916479) would recommend

> ...View All services using the Service Control Manager. Here you will need to look at what instances of SQL Server you have running on the machine.

I also have answer to that question that uses PowerShell if you're so inclined.

*2) How do I make connection with VS 2010*

For this you'll need to be more specific. Are you asking about Entity Framework, Linq To SQL, Object Data source question? Perhaps you're just asking about the Server Explorer window?