# 'OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to run a script to set up tsqlt on SQL server 2008 r2 and getting this error

> 'OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME' is not a recognized built-in function name.

on another machine with SQL 2008 r2, the script runs fine.

I can't see any difference in the users or permissions in the sql server setup for each respective machine.

this is the statement that throws the error:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION tSQLt.Private_GetOriginalTableInfo(@TableObjectId INT)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
  RETURN SELECT CAST(value AS NVARCHAR(4000)) OrgTableName,
    OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@TableObjectId)) 
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(CAST(value AS NVARCHAR(4000)))) OrgTableObjectId
    FROM sys.extended_properties
   WHERE class_desc = 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN'
     AND major_id = @TableObjectId
     AND minor_id = 0
     AND name = 'tSQLt.FakeTable_OrgTableName';
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is in fact on SQL Server 2008 R2, your database is in SQL Server 2000 compatibility mode. You can tell what mode you're in now:

```
SELECT name, compatibility_level
  FROM sys.databases
  WHERE name = N'your_database';
```

If this is 80 you will need to move up (but this will require testing):

```
ALTER DATABASE your_database SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100;
```

If you can't move up, then you can always get the schema name by joining to `sys.schemas` instead of relying on the built-in function.

---

That said, if you are on SQL Server 2005 RTM (as implied in a comment), [`OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME` was introduced in SQL Server 2005 Service Pack 2](https://sqlblog.org/2007/02/19/sql-server-2005-service-pack-2-is-here). You should not be running any system on SQL Server 2005 RTM anymore. [Go install SP4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7218) and you will be able to use this function.

Comment: how can I tell what compatibility mode it's currently in?

Comment: oh, I see it now. 9.0.1399

Comment: @JonnyCundall where are you seeing that? Seems like SQL Server 2005, not SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I saw THAT in ssms. I think I have the 2008 r2 ssms, but it's looking at a 2005 sp2 database. I could have noticed that before when I was comparing the two machines! I'm pretty sure this is the problem, although it's a little odd because google says that 2005 SP2 should recognise that function.

Comment: 9.0.1399 is 2005 RTM, not 2005 SP2. So if you are looking at 2005 RTM it won't have that function because SP2 is required (that's where it was added).

Comment: yes thanks I'd got that by that point. Actually my real problem was this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916115/sql-server-2008-installed-though-running-version-is-still-2005